# what is low nibble and why the result is different by one number

Tags: ruby

I tested following code with ruby 1.9.2 .

```
"hello".unpack('H*')
 => ["68656c6c6f"] 
> "hello".unpack('h*')
 => ["8656c6c6f6"]
```

Why the result of `h*` is off by 1. Also I thought nibble is 4 bits. However `68`, `65`, `6c`, `6c` and `6f` are all taking one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between h* and H* is the order they write the halves of the byte (nibbles). `h` writes lower half byte first and `H` writes the higher half byte first.

And yes, nibble is half of the byte - that is 4 bits.

You can check out with detailed usage of pack/unpack in [this post](http://www.codeweblog.com/ruby-string-pack-unpack-detailed-usage/)