# High nibble and low nibble what are they?

Tags: php

What is this for the function pack() in php?

I can pack a hex string with high and low nibble what is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Same as in Ruby. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768289/what-is-low-nibble-and-why-the-result-is-different-by-one-number with a link to a (very) detailed explanation.

Comment: A nibble is what can be represented by a single hex digit.

Answer (score 18):

Nibble is half a byte (0-15, or one hex digit). Low nibble are the bits 0-3; high nibble are bits 4-7.

Comment: Does it matter as long as I unpack with the same format? Also is there any preferred method ie use on over the other?

Comment: If only you read it, do whatever you want. `H` makes more sense, since that's how we normally represent hex numbers: 65 is hex `41`, not `14`.

Comment: Ye it is only me going to be reading it, H it is then thanks bud :)